# Building Batch Request in Facebook PHP SDK Api

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to build a batch request and im not sure why its not working. below is my code and the result....

```
 $getnewbids = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facebook_queue WHERE action = 'bid_change' ORDER by queued_time DESC LIMIT 25") or die (mysql_error());
$newbidcount = mysql_num_rows($getnewbids);
 $x = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getnewbids))
{
    $adgroup_id = $row['adgroup_id'];
    $bid = $row['action_data'];

    //build batch request\
    $updatebatch .= '["method"=>"POST","relative_url"=>"v2.5/'.$adgroup_id.'","body"=>"redownload=1&bid_amount='.$bid.'"';

  if($x == $newbidcount) { 
 $updatebatch .= ']';
  } else {
 $updatebatch .= '],'; 
  }
$x++;
} // endwhile

$params = '['.$updatebatch.'];';
echo json_encode($params,false);
try {
  //print_r($updatebatch);
 // echo json_encode($updatebatch);
  $response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST',
    '?batch='.urlencode($params)))->execute();
  $objects = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
  // error handling
}
```

and the output I get is...

```
"[[\"method\"=>\"POST\",\"relative_url\"=>\"v2.5\/6036240755883\",\"body\"=>\"red    ownload=1&bid_amount=1\"],    [\"method\"=>\"POST\",\"relative_url\"=>\"v2.5\/6036254528483\",\"body\"=>\"redo    wnload=1&bid_amount=3\"]];"
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookOtherException' not found in     /home/nucleusmediainc/public_html/proton/facebook/php-sdk-    v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php on line 138
```

Comment: What files are you requiring?

Comment: all the neccesary files. Its not an api issue. Its somethign with the output of the batched requests

Comment: Your error indicates that it cannot find a file from within the SDK.

Comment: Look at https://www.sammyk.me/using-the-facebook-sdk-v4-without-composer

Comment: ok, added the neccesary files... now I get  exception 'Facebook\FacebookOtherException' with message 'Unknown Exception' in facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php:138 Stack trace: #0 facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(268): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 400) #1 facebook_queue.php(142): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 {main}

Comment: I’d start by not trying to create JSON “manually” … Create the proper data structure, and then let `json_encode` do the part of making valid JSON of it.

Comment: +1 to previous comment - plus, check what the actual response from the API is, your output above is hiding the text of the error sent back from the API server